# Question about JavaScript object property

Tags: javascript

for the following simple Constructor function:

```
const test = function(Num){
            this.prop1 = Num + 1;
            this.prop2 = function(Num){
                return 4 * Num;
            }
        };

        let x = new test(5);
        console.log(x.prop2);
```

console.log gives the exact content of prop2 and not 20 which is the result of 4 * Num. now this seems expected to me but i don't understand why. any help is much appreciated

Comment: `x.prop2` is a `function` so it should be called, like this: `console.log(x.prop2());`

Comment: Because `prop2` is a function, and you are not calling the function, only referencing it. The `Num` in `function(Num)` is a *parameter* to that function, not the `Num` in `function(Num)`.

Comment: to go with @ManasKhandelwal comment, try `x.prop2(5)` or `x.prop2(10)`. you will need to specify an argument when you call it

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(x.prop2);
```

This only returns the content stored on the variable prop2 and doesn't necessarily execute the inner function. **This concept is called function closure in js**
**NB: functions are only executed when followed by ()**

Comment: Thus on your last line you should have console.log(x.prop2())

Comment: `prop2` is a function reference, not a "function closure". There's no (useful) closure in the function, either, since its `Num` param shadows the outer `Num`. `console.log(x.prop2())` would log `NaN` since it's not receiving the expected parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is prop2 print 20 when you set `test(5)`, you need to use this concept bellow:

1. f(x) = x*4;
2. x = 5;
3. f(5) = 5*4 = 20;

As code:

```
const test = function(Num){
            this.prop1 = Num + 1;
            this.prop2 = 4 * Num;
        };
```